# How can i check is input given by the user is valid website link or not?

Tags: javascript, validation

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post" >
    <input type="text" id="website" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder=" Website Link" >
    <button value="Save" name="register" class="btn btn btn-primary btn-block " type="submit" >Register</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm(){
    var valdiationWebsite = document.forms["myForm"]["website"].value;
    if (valdiationWebsite == ""){
        alert("Please Enter Website Link ");
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will show an alert when field is blank.

But, if want to know is, entered text in the input field is valid website url or simple text, then what can i do?

How can i validate the entered text?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

The `url type` is used for input fields that should contain a URL address.

The value of the url field is automatically validated when the form is submitted.

The `required` attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.

Try this

```
<input type="url" required id="website" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder=" Website Link" >
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the shortest way for which i am searching.

Comment: Not working in all browser

Answer (score 0):

try this regex 
/(ftp|http|https)://(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(/|/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!-/]))?/

Answer (score 0):

`type=url` may not support in all browsers. You can use javaScript to validate this.

```
function isValidUrl(url)
{
     return url.match(/^(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/);
}
```

Pass the user input to this `isValidUrl` function. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3809401/1923685) stack**overflow** question for better regualr expressions.